# Equals Override and LINQ GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, overriding, equals

I have two classes, one called ArcPrimitive and the other called CirclePrimitive.

```
public class ArcPrimitive : Primitive
    {
        public double Angle { get; set; }
        public double Length { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is ArcPrimitive other)
            {
                return EqualsHelpers.EqualAngles(Angle, other.Angle) && EqualsHelpers.EqualLengths(Length, other.Length);
            }
            else if (obj is ArcPrimitiveType otherType)
            {
                return EqualsHelpers.EqualAngles(Angle, otherType.Angle) && EqualsHelpers.EqualLengths(Length, otherType.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

public class CirclePrimitive : Primitive
    {
        public double Radius { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is CirclePrimitive other)
            {
                return EqualsHelpers.EqualLengths(Radius, other.Radius);
            }
            else if (obj is CirclePrimitiveType otherType)
            {
                return EqualsHelpers.EqualLengths(Radius, otherType.Radius);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Now, elsewhere in my project I have collections (List<>) of ArcPrimitive objects and CirclePrimitive objects. I would like to group together ArcPrimitive objects and CirclePrimitive objects that are considered equal when my override Equals methods are used for each class. I have attempted to do this using the GroupBy() extension method on my collections of ArcPrimitive and CirclePrimitive objects. However, the only way that I could get the GroupBy method to correctly group the objects is if I used the following overload and supplied a class that implemented the IEqualityComparer interface:

`GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)`

```
ArcPrimitiveEqualityComparer apec = new ArcPrimitiveEqualityComparer(arcPrimitives);
CirclePrimitiveEqualityComparer cpec = new CirclePrimitiveEqualityComparer(circlePrimitives);

var arcPrimitiveGroups = arcPrimitives.GroupBy(p => p, apec).ToList();
var circlePrimitiveGroups = circlePrimitives.GroupBy(p => p, cpec).ToList();
```

My issue is that the EqualityComparer classes that I had to write are incredibly not-DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), making me wonder if there is a better way.

```
public class ArcPrimitiveEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ArcPrimitive>
    {
        public Dictionary<ArcPrimitive, int> ArcHashDict { get; set; }

        public ArcPrimitiveEqualityComparer(List<ArcPrimitive> arcPrimitives)
        {
            ArcHashDict = new Dictionary<ArcPrimitive, int>();
            int hCode = 0;

            foreach (ArcPrimitive arcPrimitive in arcPrimitives)
            {
                var keys = ArcHashDict.Keys;
                bool matchFound = false;

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    if (arcPrimitive.Equals(key))
                    {
                        matchFound = true;
                    }
                }

                if (matchFound == false)
                {
                    ArcHashDict.Add(arcPrimitive, hCode);
                    hCode += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        public bool Equals(ArcPrimitive ap1, ArcPrimitive ap2)
        {
            return ap1.Equals(ap2);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ArcPrimitive ap)
        {
            foreach (var key in ArcHashDict.Keys)
            {
                if (ap.Equals(key))
                {
                    return ArcHashDict[key];
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("ArcPrimitive does not have a hash code.");
        }
    }

public class CirclePrimitiveEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CirclePrimitive>
    {
        public Dictionary<CirclePrimitive, int> CircleHashDict { get; set; }

        public CirclePrimitiveEqualityComparer(List<CirclePrimitive> circlePrimitives)
        {
            CircleHashDict = new Dictionary<CirclePrimitive, int>();
            int hCode = 0;

            foreach (CirclePrimitive circlePrimitive in circlePrimitives)
            {
                var keys = CircleHashDict.Keys;
                bool matchFound = false;

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    if (circlePrimitive.Equals(key))
                    {
                        matchFound = true;
                    }
                }

                if (matchFound == false)
                {
                    CircleHashDict.Add(circlePrimitive, hCode);
                    hCode += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(CirclePrimitive cp1, CirclePrimitive cp2)
        {
            return cp1.Equals(cp2);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(CirclePrimitive cp)
        {
            foreach (var key in CircleHashDict.Keys)
            {
                if (cp.Equals(key))
                {
                    return CircleHashDict[key];
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("CirclePrimitive does not have a hash code.");
        }
    }
```

I have pursued a couple different ways of fixing this serious repetition. One was to create a generic EqualityComparer class. The issue I faced there was that I could not access the correct Equals override when the object type is not specified in the generic class. The other method I tried was to override not only Equals but GetHashCode in my ArcPrimitive and CirclePrimitive classes in the hopes that GroupBy would just use the override methods to do the grouping. However, I could not figure out how to correctly generate a hash code for these objects, because objects that return true from Equals have to have the same hash code, and I could not figure out how to apply my custom equality methods to the hash code function to get the necessary hash codes.

Sorry for the long post, I just felt it was necessary to add the code to give the details of my issue.

**EDIT: response to NetMage comment**
This is a test to try to use IEquatable to control the equality comparison that GroupBy does for grouping and keys.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> testList = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test(1),
            new Test(1),
            new Test(2),
            new Test(3),
            new Test(3)
        };

        var result = testList.GroupBy(p => p);

        foreach (var group in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key value: {group.Key.Value}; Group count {group.Count()}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Output
        // Key value: 1; Group count: 1
        // Key value: 1; Group count: 1
        // Key value: 2; Group count: 1
        // Key value: 3; Group count: 1
        // Key value: 3; Group count: 1

    }
}

class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Test(int val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public bool Equals(Test other)
    {
        return Value == other.Value;
    }
}
```

As you can see, each object becomes a key and none are grouped together, even though I wanted objects with the same `Value` property to be grouped together.

Comment: If you rewind a bit, what is your end goal? `GroupBy` sounds like a strange choice for equality comparison. Also the `IEqualityComparer` in the `GroupBy` overload is supposed to *compare the selected keys* not the whole object.

Comment: If your primitives implement `IEquatable<T>` then `GroupBy` should use their own equality by default.

Comment: @Xerillio The goal is to group items considered similar/equal based on the comparisons that I am doing in the override Equals methods I have above. I would like to reach a point where I have a grouping of objects that are considered equal so that I can store how many copies of equal objects are in the group and the characteristic object that represents the group as the key (that is why I pass the entire object in as the keyselector for groupby).

Comment: @NetMage see above edit for my attempt to do what you suggest. With IEquatable implemented I cannot get GroupBy to use my Equals method for comparing keys about grouping objects.

Comment: See if overriding `GetHashCode` in your test class solves that problem.

Comment: Indeed - basically you're overriding Equals but *not* overriding GetHashCode in a compatible way, which will *always* lead to problems with hash-based comparisons.

Comment: You also haven't shown `EqualsHelpers.EqualLengths`, but I wouldn't be at all surprised to see that with that code in place, you're violating other aspects of the Equals contract.

Comment: From the docs for `IEquatable<T>`: "If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode()` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `Equals(T)` method." Your test class doesn't do that.

Comment: You need to override `GetHashCode` as well: `public override int GetHashCode() => Value;`  and then `GroupBy` will work as expected.

Comment: @JonSkeet Seems like the language should have a way to enforce that (e.g. `IEquatable<T>` to include `GetHashCode`).

Comment: @NetMage: That would be ideal, yes. C# does enforce that if you override `Equals(object)`, you also override `GetHashCode` - but that doesn't help with `IEquatable<T>`. It also doesn't appear to have helped to OP, who "works around it" by calling `base.GetHashCode()` in their "primitive" implementations :(

Answer (score 2):

Properly working version of `IEquatable<T>` example:

```
void Main() {
    var testList = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 }.Select(n => new Test(n)).ToList();

    var result = testList.GroupBy(p => p);

    foreach (var group in result)
        Console.WriteLine($"Key value: {group.Key.Value}; Group count {group.Count()}");

    // Output
    //Key value: 1; Group count 2
    //Key value: 2; Group count 1
    //Key value: 3; Group count 2
}

class Test : IEquatable<Test> {
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Test(int val) => Value = val;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Test otherTest && this.Equals(otherTest);
    public bool Equals(Test other) => other is not null && Value == other.Value;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Value;
    public static bool operator==(Test aTest, Test bTest) => aTest is not null && aTest.Equals(bTest);
    public static bool operator!=(Test aTest, Test bTest) => !(aTest == bTest);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this example is oversimplified compared to my actual implementation. The hash codes for my primitives can't be the values of their properties because I have to compare two objects by their property values with tolerances, not just by equality. What I have realized is that I may need to do a separate post where I ask for help coming up with a strategy for a proper hash code function that takes into account tolerances when comparing the values of the properties on my objects. Currently I get around this by making a```Dictionary<ArcPrimitive, int>``` to generate correct hash codes.

Comment: @jperna7254 The hazards of not asking the actual question you need to answer.

Comment: @jperna7254 Thinking about it, without knowing more about your data distribution, I believe the best you can do is `GetHashCode() => 1`. With an equality using tolerances, you can have `a == b` and `b == c` but not `a == c`, which means you can't compute a bucket for equal values.